# Confusion with properties

Tags: python, properties

I am new to using properties, so I put together a simple test as shown below. In my tests, I made two classes "Test1" and "Test2" where each is meant to hold one value. I am attempting to use a property to govern access to the pseudo-hidden "val" attribute. This current test does not restrict any inputs or outputs of the "val" attribute as this program was only meant as a proof of concept. The two test classes shown below yield the same results and are supposed to represent the different methods to construct a property. The example uses for properties I am referring to are found on the [python docs here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property).

As per the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property):

> If then c is an instance of C, c.x will invoke the getter, c.x = value will invoke the setter and del c.x the deleter.

where C is their test class. I thought that by setting the value the way I did would change _val and leave val as a property. However it seems to me that my method of accessing the properties setter is actually replacing the property with the integer `5` unless I am mistaken. I hope someone can clarify my confusion.

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        self._val = 0

    def setVal(self,newVal):
        self._val = newVal
    val = property(lambda self: self._val, setVal, None, "Property for value")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Value: {}".format(self.val)

class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        self._val = 0

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val

    @val.setter
    def setVal(self,newVal):
        self._val = newVal

    def __str__(self):
        return "Value: {}".format(self.val)

def verify(a):
    print("\nCheck with {}".format(a.__class__.__name__))
    print("Value check:",a.val)
    a.val = 5
    print("Value after a.val = 5 is:",a.val)
    print("The actual value is:",a._val)

def main():
    verify(Test1())
    verify(Test2())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property):

> `property([fget[, fset[, fdel[, doc]]]])`
>
> Return a property attribute for **new-style classes** (classes that derive from object).

Descriptors are only invoked for new style objects or classes. Your using old-style classes. Inherits from a base type `object`:

```
class Test1(object):
    # your code

class Test2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._val = 0
    
    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val
    
    @val.setter
    def val(self,newVal): # should be named as property
        self._val = newVal
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Value: {}".format(self.val)
```

This work fine:

```
>>> verify(Test1())

Check with Test1
('Value check:', 0)
('Value after a.val = 5 is:', 5)
('The actual value is:', 5)
```

Read more about [difference between new-style classes and classic classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle).

Comment: Thank you for that article. However I do have one more question. I changed each class to parent to the class `object` just as you stated. Test1 works flawlessly, however Test2 provides me with the error: `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jakebird451, excuse me, on my side of the planet was a night. :) From documentation: "Be sure to give the additional functions the same name as the original property". You setter-function should be named `val` in this case.